# How to search for files in different directories recursively in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, full-text-search

Visual Studio Code (as of version 1.41.1) is obviously very limited in regard of its file search. It seems to only allow to either search in folders recursively or in specific files, but it doesn't allow both.

**Search in folders recursively**

- `path/to/folder/` searches in any directories within subpaths matching `path/to/folder` including all subdirectories with no restriction in file names.
- `./path/to/folder/, ./path/to/another/folder` searches in the directories with the paths `path/to/folder` and `path/to/another/folder` relative to the project's root directory.

**Search in files**

- `foo.bar` searches in all files named `foo.bar`.
- `*.foo, *.bar` searches in all files with the extensions `foo` or `bar`.
- `./path/to/folder/*/*.foo` searches in all files with the extension `foo` that lie in a direct subdirectory of `path/to/folder/` relative to the project's root directory.

**Search in folders recursively and filter by file name**

So, how to combine these two searches, i.e. filter the search by file names but search in specific directories with all their subdirectories?

In other editors like Eclipse you normally have two different fields for file names and folders, making it easy to specify them individually and avoid having to repeat yourself for multiple folders and file names. Therefore I have already created an [enhancement request in the VSCode bug tracker asking to add a separate field for the folder](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80564).

Comment: If I understand correctly, doesn't using the globstar `**` solve your issue?  So `./path/to/folder/**/*.foo` searches in all subdirectories of whatever depth of the `folder` folder.  It seems to work in my testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my testing, using the globstar does provide the functionality you desire.

https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer:

> `**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero
>   or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does
>   not crawl symlinked directories.

So that `./path/to/folder/**/*.foo` for example searches within all subdirectories of `folder` no matter how deep within files with the `foo` extension.

Same at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options:

> `**` to match any number of path segments, including none

Comment: You're right. I simply didn't know you can use the "globstar" in the search as there are no hints about it in the UI and no one I know using VSCode knew about that. (Besides that I didn't hear the name "globstar". I called that double-asterisk before.) Thank you very much for that note!